# Unable to install screwdriver charts on EKS cluster

Tags: screwdriver-cd

I am trying to do `helm install . --name my-screwdriver --namespace your-namespace` step in `https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver-chart` to spin up a screwdriver instance on eks cluster. I am running into `Error: YAML parse error on screwdriver/templates/api.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 92: found character that cannot start any token` error.

I have followed the previous steps of example-scm-settings, values.yaml and screwdriver-api-secrets.yaml file as mentioned in the readme.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using tabs for indentation. YAML doesn't allow tabs; it requires spaces.

Comment: please check this video for better understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgkOTiHzgeI

Comment: any clue why this "found character that cannot start any token error"  has come. It generally comes because of the tab.

Comment: I remember you used to order screwdriver for the drink!

Comment: Also some times a Vodka Cranberry！

Answer (score 0):

This error was because of incorrect Postgress setup.